How to find out throughput and read performance of SSD from a C++ application?
I am writing an application that uses io_uring to read a file from SSD. My task is to measure the read performance and throughput of the SSD from the C++ application. I tried using the data frrom /proc/diskstats but the values i get are 0. I tried using perf but the result is same and the values are 0. For development I am using ubuntu on WSL2.
I wrote the following code to get data from /proc/diskstats.
DiskStats getDiskStats(const std::string& device_name) {
    std::ifstream file("/proc/diskstats");
    std::string line;
    DiskStats stats = {};

    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        std::istringstream ss(line);
        std::string device;
        unsigned long dummy;
        ss >> dummy >> dummy >> device;

        if (device == device_name) {
            ss >> stats.reads_completed >> stats.reads_merged >> stats.sectors_read >> stats.time_reading
               >> stats.writes_completed >> stats.writes_merged >> stats.sectors_written >> stats.time_writing;
            break;
        }
    }

    return stats;
}

void getSSDUtil(const DiskStats& before, const DiskStats& after, double duration_us) {
    DiskStats diff = after - before;
    double sectors_read = diff.sectors_read;
    double sector_size = 512; // Assume 512 bytes per sector
    double bytes_read = sectors_read * sector_size;
    double throughput = bytes_read / (duration_us / 1e6); // bytes per second

    spdlog::info("Sectors read: {}", sectors_read);
    spdlog::info("Bytes read: {}", bytes_read);
    spdlog::info("Throughput: {} B/s", throughput);
}


Note that WSL2 is a VM; it won't be directly accessing your SSD, only talking to the host Windows kernel for I/O.  Perhaps paravirtualized, IDK what they do.  But I'm not shocked that /proc/diskstats doesn't show any I/O.

If you can flush caches first, or use a large enough I/O size that you can defeat read caches, you could just count how many bytes your program reads and divide by how long it took.  (For flushing caches, Windows probably has caching outside the VM.)

To measure the drive, you want to work as directly as possible with the drive. I'd use a native Windows app that opens a file with CreateFile, and specified FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, to measure reading and writing the file on the actual drive, rather than measuring the cache.

@PeterCordes I am reading a file of 53 MB which takes around 0.3 seconds to read and before running the program i flush the caches as well but still no changes in the /proc/diskstats records. I wrote a python program to execute the c++ application and then measure bytes read from disk using psutil but it seems the values reported are greatly different. It measures 1 MB block read whereas the file is of 53 MB

@JerryCoffin The program is written is compiled in WSL2 as the application needs the liburing library to read a file. I need the SSD values as reported from WSL2

@Dexter0411: that might be an interesting thing to measure in itself, but it's nearly impossible to guess how much of what you're measuring is the drive, and how the layer upon layer of software between your code and the drive.

@JerryCoffin Found a hack to find out the SSD read speed and throughput. I wrote a python script to execute the c++ application in WSL environment from windows and using psutil library I can get the SSD performance. Maybe you guys can comment on the accuracy. Will post the code if you need.
